# What would cause node process.version to return undefined?

Tags: azure, process, version

So I've been debugging this issue for a while now and this is where I'm at...

I'm trying to use the `azure-storage-node` package from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) and I'm having issues with `process.version` returning undefined. More specifically, it's being caused by the following line:

`const azure = require('azure-storage');`

The error I'm getting is:

[image]

For what it's worth, I'm getting this issue when trying to use the Azure package with the following [project](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard). However, when I use the same package and call the require statement on a new Vue project, it works just fine, so the issue must be within environment/setup I'm guessing?

What would cause process.version to return undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`azure-storage-node` has special version for use in web browsers. If you try to use the Node version (e.g., `npm install azure-storage` and then `require('azure-storage');`) in a browser-based application, then you will indeed get the error you describe, because there is no node process in a web browser.

Instead, you need to use the [Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library for Browsers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/browser/README.md), which is a browser-specific build of the library. The linked page has instructions for using the pre-built library, or for building it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Nikolas is right, seemingly related GitHub Issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/516